# Given $a_n=2⋅a_{n−1}−3$ with $a_1=5$, prove by induction that $a_n=2^n +3 \forall n≥1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider the following recurrence relation: 
$$a_n=2⋅a_{n−1}−3$$ with $a_1=5$

Prove by induction that $$a_n=2^n +3 \forall n≥1$$

I know how to do a proof by induction. But I am unsure as to how this answer will shape.

Comment: look at these [examples](https://cims.nyu.edu/~kiryl/teaching/aa/review1.pdf), MI proofs are basically of same routines/steps.

Answer (score 1):

Base Case:

For $n=1$,
$$LHS=a_1=2^{1}+3=5=RHS$$

---

Inductive hypothesis:

Let for some $n=k \in\mathbb N$,
$$a_k=2^{k}+3$$

---

Inductive step:
$$a_{k+1}=2\cdot a_k-3=2(2^k+3)-3=2^{k+1}+6-3=2^{k+1}+3$$
Hence, given that it is true for $k$, it is true for $k+1$.

We can thus conclude that it is true for all $n\ge1$.

Answer (score 1):

Base case : I let you do.

Inductive case : Suppose it is true up to $n$ : Then
$$
a_{n+1} = 2 \cdot a_n - 3 \overset{(*)}{=} 2 \cdot (2^n + 3)-3
$$
$(*)$ Inductive hypothesis.

I'll let you conclude.

Comment: Some avenging angel has passed. :(

Comment: Dat downvote...

Comment: Somebody is convinced that answering easy questions warrants a downvote. I obviously disagree.